# Track Mouse Position in an Application without Nib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm making a Cocoa application and I wanna implement a Screen Hot Corners System (Just like Exposé Active Corners). My application don't have a Nib file and It'll run at the background. I wanna know how to constantly track mouse position, in order to know if the cursor reaches one of the screen corners, to invoke a method. Could someone help me?
本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [`CGEventTap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreate) for the events you're interested in (probably just `kCGEventMouseMoved`).